# "cordova run android" does not reflect changes on device/emulator

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have tried many different solutions from google to get new changes reflected but NO LUCK.

**Things Tried.**
- platform remove and add again
- deleting APK file
- setting cache off in index.html
- changing version in config file
- modifying app_id
- etc.

```
ionic info

global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.0

System:

    Node       : v6.11.0
    OS         : Windows 7
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 5.0.3
```

Comment: are the changes reflected in `ionic serve` ?

Comment: I'm using SQLIte and querying it ... and using console.log for debug.. No changes made when messages or querys are changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying almost all the solutions provided by different members of ionic forum and stackoverflow I found out that If I run

```
ionic serve
```

then stopping it, and then

```
cordova run android
```

have solved my problem. Without following this sequence I'm not able to see the changes reflected directly on android device/emulator.

I don't know the exact logic behind it but in my case it is working like this.

Comment: i know this is way too old, but the explanation behind this is ionic serve will update the www folder from the app folder... so another solution is to just delete the www folder and do ionic cordova run android

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the existing app, run a `cordova prepare` and try re-running the app. Sometimes the existing app might not get overwritten properly. Also for your changes to propagate to the platform folder, a prepare has to be executed.

Comment: Yup ... cordova prepare works .. but only when I leave the workstation idle for sometime (dont know exact) and later i followed you and worked but not all the times. Any Guesses ?

Comment: Execution of `cordova prepare` takes some time. So you will have to wait till the complete execution is done. Running a `cordova clean` and then executing `cordova prepare` before running the app again should solve your problem.

Comment: No it is not working like I'm making changes and running those commands to check whether it has reflected or not ...... and I found out that it is not reflecting immediately. Looking for some solution in which i dont need to wait...and should reflect changes immediately.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for following command

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload -cs
```

For more information and details see

```
ionic cordova run android --help
```